# Hook failed with error code 2

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

> 1> 
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js:
>   line 2: 1>  : command not found 1> 
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js:
>   line 3: //: is a directory 1> 
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js:
>   line 4: //: is a directory 1> 
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js:
>   line 5: //: is a directory 1> 
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js:
>   line 6: prepare: command not found 1> 
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js:
>   line 6: //: is a directory 1> 
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js:
>   line 7: //: is a directory 1> 
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js:
>   line 8: //: is a directory 1> 
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js:
>   line 9: //: is a directory 1> 
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js:
>   line 10: 1>  : command not found 1> 
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js:
>   line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `(' 1> 
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js:
>   line 11:`var fs = require('fs'); 1>  ' 1>  Command finished with
>   error code 2:
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp
>   1>  为 buildNumber 583 生成应用失败: Hook failed with error code 2:
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
>   1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: 生成服务器 生成失败，错误 Hook failed
>   with error code 2:
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
>   中的远程生成错误 - 1 1>  Error 生成服务器 生成失败，错误 Hook failed with error code 2:
>   /Users/hu/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/583/cordovaApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
>   中的远程生成错误 - {1}

when I start the remote agent in secure mode for vs2015,debug model:iphone6s

Comment: Try copy/pasting a new copy of the hooks file. It seems like it has invalid characters such as wrong line endings. Or, change the line endings yourself in VS.

Comment: @huxiaozhong did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with wrong line endings. On the OS/X side you need LF line endings, the 010_add_platform_class.js file however seems to have CRLF line endings.

So you need to change the line endings of the file 010_add_platform_class.js to LF instead of CRLF on your Windows machine.

As Visual Studio doesn't have an option to change line endings as far as I know, you can use Visual Studio Code to do that. In VS Code you have a label in the bottom right of the status bar that says CRLF. When you click that you can change the line endings to LF.